# Why complex conjugate roots of polynomials with real coefficients have the same multiplicity?

Tags: polynomials

Let

$$f(x)=(x-z_1)^{k_1}(x-\overline{z_1})^{l_1} \cdot  ... \cdot (x-z_n)^{k_n} (x-\overline{z_n})^{l_n}g(x),$$

where $z_i$ are different complex numbers with nonzero imaginaris parts, $k_i, l_i $ are natural numbers, $g$ is a real polynom and $g(z_i)\neq 0$ for $i=1,...,n$.

Why, if $f$ is a real polynom, then $k_i=l_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$?

Comment: The shortest answer is, because $\overline{f(\overline{z})} = f(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. If you don't know any complex analysis yet, that may however not be helpful. Do you know any complex analysis yet?

Comment: I prefer more elementary ways.

Comment: @user111 Are you saying you don't want to use the above property? It's one of the most elementary properties about complex numbers. It doesn't make much sense to tackle a problem about complex numbers without knowing that (even if it is possible), in my opinon.

Comment: @Git Gud Could you write any idea of this proof?

Comment: @Richard I'm guessing you know how to do it, so unless the OP asks me too, I won't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z$ is a zero of $f(x)$, let $m$ be the multiplicity of $z$ as a root of $f$.
Then $(x-z)^m$ divides $f(x)$.  Taking conjugates, and using that $f(x)$ has real coeffs., we see that $(x   -\overline{z})^m$ also divides $f(x)$.  Thus $\overline{z}$ has multiplicity at least $m$.  Applying the same argument, with $\overline{z}$ in place of $z$, and using that $\overline{\overline{z}} = z$,
we see that in fact the multiplicities of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ as roots of $f$
coincide.

Answer (score 1):

This will be more a heuristic solution, I'll leave it to you to formalize it if desired.

The only irreducible real polynomials are of the form $(x-a)$ and $(x^2+bx+a)$, where $(b^2-4a) < 0$. In the latter case, the polynomial breaks down in $\mathbf{C}$ and we get conjugate imaginary roots, $z, \bar{z}$.

In your case,  you have factors of the form $(x-z)$, where $z$ is complex with nonzero imaginary part. Thus, we need all the imaginary parts of the $z_i$'s to "cancel". The only way this can happen is if each $(x-z_i)$ is multiplied by its conjugate root $(x-\bar{z_i})$. Then, each root meets with its conjugate to create an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbf{R}$ of the second form above. So, we must have the multiplicity of each root the same as that of its conjugate.

You may want to think what happens if you multiply $z_1 \cdot z_2$. Or what your polynomial would look like if $k_i \neq l_i$ for some $i$. Essentially, there is a necessary symmetry in your polynomial, since it is real.